# How to calculate RMS noise from datasheet?

Tags: noise, snr, dds, calculation

I am using an AD9833 DDS as a sine signal source for my circuit. The bandwidth will be 3.5MHz. I would like to calculate the RMS noise of the DDS for my bandwidth. The datasheet has a SNR specification for a test frequency.

[image: AD9833 SNR]

The AD9833 can create sine signals up to 12.5MHz with a clock signal of 25MHz. What bandwidth does the datasheet refer to? Is it 12.5 MHz?

The amplitude of the output signal is about 0.3V. I thought I could calculate the RMS noise like this:

$$ V_{RMS\,12.5MHz}= \cfrac{0.3\,V/\sqrt{2}}{10^{\frac{60dB}{20}}}= 212\mu V $$

$$ e_{AD9833}=\cfrac{212\mu V}{\sqrt{12.5MHz}}=60\frac{nV}{\sqrt{Hz}} $$

$$ V_{RMS\,3.5MHz} = 60\frac{nV}{\sqrt{Hz}}\cdot \sqrt{3.5\,MHz}=112\mu V  $$

Is this calculation any good?

Comment: Just use the noise spectral graphs. Figures 14-20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE&O ...

> How to calculate RMS noise from datasheet?

S/N ratio is just defined for 1 frequency \$Fmclk=25 MHz\$ and \$Fout=Fmclk/4096\$.
But I would not consider it is a **"normal" s/n ratio**.

Here, I should only use the definition of SFDR ...

> The **wideband SFDR** gives the magnitude of the largest spur or harmonic relative to the magnitude of the fundamental frequency in the zero to Nyquist bandwidth, **0 to Fmclk/2**.
> The **narrow-band SFDR** gives the **attenuation** of the **largest spur or harmonic** in a *bandwidth of **±200 kHz** about the fundamental frequency*.

And SNR ...

> **SNR** is the **ratio** of the **RMS value of the measured output signal to the RMS sum** of *all other spectral components below the Nyquist frequency*

So, if I wanted a very "good" signal & s/n ratio, I should use a **"tracking" band-pass filter** centered on the output frequency.

Comment: I can't put a bandpass filter on the output because I will also need low frequencies. I did not consider the SDFR though.

Comment: Ok. for the band-pass, if you use "random" frequencies very different.